# illegal, left operand has type 'DWORD [29]'

Tags: c++, enums

I'm pretty new to C++ and I'm really stuck here.

```
if (bAk == 1)
{
    int fireRate = 134;

    if (shotTiming < 30)
    {
        int valueX = (AssaultRifle::recoilTableX[shotTiming] * 0.48) + shakerNum;
        int smoothingX = valueX / 5;
        int valueY = (AssaultRifle::recoilTableY[shotTiming] * 0.48) + shakerNum;
        int smoothingY = valueY / 5;
        Sleep(3);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            mouse_move(valueX, valueY);
            Sleep(fireRate / 5);
        }
        shotTiming++;
        cout << valueX;
    }
}
```

The only build error I am getting at this point is `illegal, left operand has type 'DWORD [29]'` Both int values of `recoilTable` are saying that the `AssaultRifle` namespace must have `arithmetic or unscoped enum type`. I just need to be put in the right direction of finishing it.

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

namespace AssaultRifle
{
    const size_t MAX_INDEX_WEAPON = 1;
    const size_t MAX_INDEX_RECOIL = 29;
    DWORD recoilTableY[MAX_INDEX_WEAPON][MAX_INDEX_RECOIL] = {
        { 40, 48, 48, 48, 33, 33, 28, 24, 16, 13, 18, 22, 24, 29, 33, 33, 33, 29, 22, 20, 17, 17, 17, 17, 20, 27, 27, 27, 26 }
    };
    DWORD recoilTableX[MAX_INDEX_WEAPON][MAX_INDEX_RECOIL] = {
        { -36, 5, -59, -49, 3, 20, 25, 45, 43, 32, 82, 8, 43, -32, -25, -40, -35, -32, -43 , -42, -42, -55, -25, 15, 20, 35, 50, 62, 40 }
    };
}
```

Comment: I added a little more context in the post.

Comment: @TylerKanz your error is that you try to multiply an array with constant double value.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Thank you! Sorry Im very new. Where are you seeing this at?

Comment: You are missing the other dimension `[0]` should be added to that line..

Comment: `AssaultRifle::recoilTableY[shotTiming]` is an array with 29 items. Although you are likely out of bounds with the `shotTiming` since the only valid value is 0.

Comment: Look at both of your array declarations. Count the number of pairs of `[]`. Now look at how you're trying to use the arrays. Count the number of pairs of `[]`. Are they the same? If not, you've identified the problem.

Comment: @drescherjm So where should I go with that array?

Comment: change `AssaultRifle::recoilTableY[shotTiming]` to `AssaultRifle::recoilTableY[0][shotTiming]`

Comment: `DWORD` also is supposed to be an unsigned 32 bit integer you may want to reconsider that type if you need negative values.

Answer (score 2):

Your `recoilTableX` and `recoilTableY` arrays are both **2-dimensional** <sup>1</sup>:

```
DWORD recoilTableY[<# elements in first dimension>][<# elements in second dimension>] = {...};
DWORD recoilTableX[<# elements in first dimension>][<# elements in second dimension>] = {...};
```

But when reading individual values from the arrays, your code is indexing into only the **first dimension**.  That is why you are getting the error, as you can't access an entire array as a single integer like you are attempting to do.  You have to specify indexes for ALL of the available dimensions.

Change this:

```
AssaultRifle::recoilTableX[shotTiming]
AssaultRifle::recoilTableY[shotTiming]
```

To this instead:

```
AssaultRifle::recoilTableX[0][shotTiming]
AssaultRifle::recoilTableY[0][shotTiming]
```

`MAX_INDEX_WEAPON` is 1, so there is only 1 slot in the first dimension of the arrays, so the ONLY valid index in the first dimension is 0, which makes the first dimension pretty useless and should be removed, unless you are planning on adding values for additional weapons in the future.

`MAX_INDEX_RECOIL` is 29, so there are 29 slots in the second dimension of the arrays, so the ONLY valid indexes in the second dimension are 0..28 inclusive, but your code allows index 29 to be accessed.

The *NAMES* of your `MAX_INDEX_WEAPON` and `MAX_INDEX_RECOIL` constants are misleading, as they are not actually being used as indexes at all.

<sup>1: also, your arrays should be declared as `const`.</sup>

Try this instead:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

namespace AssaultRifle
{
    const size_t MAX_WEAPONS = 1;
    const size_t MAX_RECOILS = 29;
    const int recoilTableY[MAX_WEAPONS][MAX_RECOILS] = {
        { { 40, 48, 48, 48, 33, 33, 28, 24, 16, 13, 18, 22, 24, 29, 33, 33, 33, 29, 22, 20, 17, 17, 17, 17, 20, 27, 27, 27, 26 } }
    };
    const int recoilTableX[MAX_WEAPONS][MAX_RECOILS] = {
        { { -36, 5, -59, -49, 3, 20, 25, 45, 43, 32, 82, 8, 43, -32, -25, -40, -35, -32, -43 , -42, -42, -55, -25, 15, 20, 35, 50, 62, 40 } }
    };
}
```

```
if (bAk == 1)
{
    int fireRate = 134;

    if (shotTiming < AssaultRifle::MAX_RECOILS)
    {
        int valueX = (AssaultRifle::recoilTableX[0][shotTiming] * 0.48) + shakerNum;
        int smoothingX = valueX / 5;
        int valueY = (AssaultRifle::recoilTableY[0][shotTiming] * 0.48) + shakerNum;
        int smoothingY = valueY / 5;
        Sleep(3);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            mouse_move(valueX, valueY);
            Sleep(fireRate / 5);
        }
        shotTiming++;
        cout << valueX;
    }
}
```

Comment: In "if (shotTiming < MAX_RECOILS)" MAX_RECOILS is undefined though.

Comment: @TylerKanz fixed